# Single letter chemical elements on a 2x2 grid

Tags: puzzle-identification, explanation, chemistry

In the past somebody showed me the puzzle below. I remember the answer but not the entire solution. Here it goes:

> On a grid of 2x2 put four single letter chemical elements. The result should have two letter elements on the horizontal, vertical and diagonal.

Comment: So, what exactly is the question??

Comment: Well I thought there should be a element in every direction. So ltr and rtl. By now I know that's impossible. What frustrated me is that there are two possibilities depending on the direction you read the diagonal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is:

First row:

> S N

Second row:

> B I

The elements are:

> Sn - Tin, Bi - Bismuth, Sb - Antimony, Ni - Nickel, Si - Silicon, Nb - Niobium

Comment: I've just deleted my comment cause you spotted the diagonals :)

Comment: +1 I saw the answer for the diagonal from upper left to lower right, but did not consider the one from lower left to upper right.

Comment: How is this not accepted and the other, later one is accepted?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος both answers are correct if you reverse the reading direction of the diagonal. To me left-to-right seems more logical than top-to-bottem. Although 11 people disagree. Is there a rule of thumb when reading diagonally? I can't find anything about it on the web.

Answer (score 4):

Taking a quick look at a period chart, the only valid answer, giving your hint is:

> SB
>  NI

for

> Antimony (Sb)
>  Tin (Sn)
>  Silicon (Si)
>  Nickel (Ni)
>  Bismuth (Bi)

Comment: @PeterJanssen There is no element with the symbol Bn

Comment: It seems that there is consensus about what direction a diagonal needs to be read.

Comment: Nb is niobium, which isn't explicitly listed in the elements above.

Comment: How do you know this is the only answer? (The search space is pretty small, so I suppose exhaustive search would be trivial)

Comment: The original question had the letters I, s, b, and n in the hint.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> +-+-+
> |S|N|
> +-+-+
> |I|B|
> +-+-+
>
> S: Sulfur
> Si: Silicon
> Sb: Antimony
> Sn: Tin
> I: Iodine
> In: Indium
> N: Nitrogen
> Ni: Nickel
> Nb: Niobium
> B: Boron
> Bi: Bismuth
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Row entries: 2
> Column entries: 2
> Total entries: 4
> Additional entries: 11
> Other entries: [CHEM_EL] 11 [CHEM_EL_L2] 7
> Total: 15
> Other tallies: [DUPE] 0
> ```

Answer (score 2):

First  row:

> SC

Second row:

> NO

And the elements are:

> Scandium (Sc), Cesium (Cs), Nobelium (No), Tin (Sn), Cobalt (Co), Copernicium (CN -diagonal), Osmium (Os - diagonal)

Comment: Kudos for using Cn. Wasn't named when I first heard about this puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is

> Sc and In
> Sc=Scandium, S=Sulfur, C=Carbon
> In=Indium, I=Iodine, N=Nitrogen
> Sn=Tin
>  S  C
>  I  N

Comment: Neither Ci nor Ic is a chemical element

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please double-check the question contents and your answer to see if it is correct. Here, the elements `Ci` and `Ic` are specified, but they do not exist.